# Proving a set is uncountable by determining its cardinality

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, cardinals

I was working on this problem for class

> B is the set of all infinite binary strings. Show B is uncountable.

The given answer uses a diagonal argument similar to the Cantor proof, however that wasn't my first thought.

I first thought to do the following:

Index every digit in a binary string $1,2,3,...$. The number of digits in a particular string is $\mathbb{N}$, and since each digit can earlier be a $0,1$ we have that our set contains
$$
2^{|\mathbb{N}|}
$$
Strings, which is the same as the cardinality of the continuum. Therefore, B is uncountable.

Is this sufficient? I'm not sure how infinite cardinalities hold up to operations like that.

Comment: That is perfect, just worded a bit weirdly. What you want to say is that infinite binary strings can be enumerated by the naturals, and at each position, we can have a $0$ or $1$. That means that there is an obvious bijection between the set of binary strings and the set of functions from $\mathbb N\to\{0,1\}$. However, the cardinality of the latter is $2^\mathbb N$, which is known to be uncountable.

Comment: Another variant of this same idea is to enumerate the positions in the binary string with the naturals, and then consider the subset of all naturals where the digit in that place is $0$. Note that for any subset of the naturals, there exists a binary string that outputs the subset via this process. That means that there is a surjection from the set of binary strings to the powerset of $\mathbb N$, which is clearly uncoutanble.

Comment: To me, this sounds like you are "reducing" the question to the same question.

Comment: @Michael To me, it looks more like translating the problem to a very similar problem that they have already solved. Infinite binary strings and subsets of $\Bbb N$ and real numbers in $[0,1)$ aren't _quite_ the same, after all.

Comment: @Arthur I agree. Understanding how to construct bijections may be seen as trivial, but for a first encounter, it's quite important. After all, this was quite non-obvious when it was first introduced.

Comment: @Arthur : You may be making some additional assumptions about what the asker is stating: I observe that _you_ mentioned subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, the asker did not.  The asker writes $2^{|\mathbb{N}|}$ (with some unknown interpretation)  instead of $2^{\mathbb{N}}$.  Are you sure the asker knows what you are talking about when you say "subsets of $\mathbb{N}$" or $2^{\mathbb{N}}$? [I also wonder how any proof about subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ that they had seen before would be different from what they are being asked to prove.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already know that $2^{\Bbb N}$ is uncountable, then what you have there is enough. As you have shown that there is an injection $2^{\Bbb N}\to B$, which implies
$$
\left\lvert2^{\Bbb N}\right\rvert\leq |B|
$$